# Android can't change the status bar with Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

It is always full screen when I use unity on Android, so I set some window flag to change the status bar's style. It doesn't work well! However, Unity can change the status bar‘s style using the same method (get window to change window flag) by script. I don't know why unity can change it and when to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnityPalyer will set the activity for fullScreen and use setSystemUiVisibility(7) at every frame.